# Bug with Excel form control - scrollbar keeps scrolling

Tags: excel

I'm creating a dynamic chart using an Excel form control -- the scrollbar -- and the way this works is exactly as described on http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/animation-interaction-and-dynamic-excel-charts/ (towards the bottom). I have a chart of data, and a column called "Chart source" that just does an index match based on the scrollbar's linked number. When you click through the scrollbar, it updates the chart source column and thus the chart.

The problem I'm having is that when I click the scrollbar, it keeps scrolling all the way, to either the left or the right, instead of moving incrementally one by one. The number counts through 1 by 1, but it goes all the way as if I were continuously clicking the button. This behavior stops in its tracks if I click and then move the mouse out of the arrow area. I've tried messing with the form control's "incremental change" and "page change" options to no avail. Things that do work: I can click and drag the scrollbar itself to the place I want it. I can type a new number in the cell linked to the scrollbar, and the scrollbar will jump to the right position.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this bug?

EDIT: I figured out the problem. This is a bug in Excel. If you are in "Page Break Preview" mode instead of "Normal" mode, this behavior will happen. Switching back to "Normal" mode (the first of the three icons in the bottom right next to the zoom) fixes this behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. This is a bug in Excel. If you are in "Page Break Preview" mode instead of "Normal" mode, this behavior will happen. Switching back to "Normal" mode (the first of the three icons in the bottom right next to the zoom)

Comment: Not solving for me, I was working in normal mode from teh beginning (MS Office 2019)

Comment: It's possible they changed the behavior in the >8 years since I posted this answer. I believe my answer would've applied to Office 2010.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when calculations that result from the changed value that is controlled by the scroll bar, takes too long.  Changing to Manual calculation mode resolves the problem (although of course is not necessarily desirable in all cases)...

(see http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/slider-bar-continues-increment-mouse-hovers-over-arrow-t3064239.html)

Answer (score 0):

The same has been happening to me, but my excel sheet was in "normal" mode.I believe the original answer is correct. I noticed this happens when I press a combination of keys or my hand lightly brushes across bottom pf laptop. Very annoying. Finally I sit and wait for the scrolling to stop then click back to top of sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer... I have the problem with one type of worksheet, but only when another worksheet with VBA code is open. A fix might be, in the first worksheet:
File\Options\Advanced\Formulas\un-check Enable Multi-Threaded Calculation